# Distinct employee name sum of purchase amount?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have  this query I have created. It returns over 35000+ records for employees and their purchases for 1 year. I am trying to have the query return only 1 instance of the employee (name) and the total purchase amount instead of indivdual records. Is this possible?

```
SELECT

distinct employee.employee_no,

sum(employee_purchase.purchase_amount) as 'Purchase Amount',

--employee.employee_no,

employee.employee_first_name,

employee.employee_last_name,

employee.home_store_no,

employee_purchase.transaction_date,

employee_purchase.employee_discount_amount


FROM

employee


INNER JOIN

employee_purchase ON employee.employee_no =

employee_purchase.employee_no



where

transaction_date between ('2010-06-30 00:00:00') and ('2011-04-26 00:00:00')


group by employee.employee_no, employee.employee_first_name, employee.employee_last_name,

employee.home_store_no,

employee_purchase.transaction_date,

employee_purchase.employee_discount_amount


order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your DISTINCT, and remove the transaction data. Think about it: if you want to sum over all transactions, you cannot also have information about a single transaction.

```
SELECT
  employee.employee_no,
  sum(employee_purchase.purchase_amount) as 'Purchase Amount',
  employee.employee_first_name,
  employee.employee_last_name,
  employee.home_store_no
FROM
  employee
INNER JOIN employee_purchase ON employee.employee_no = employee_purchase.employee_no
where
transaction_date between ('2010-06-30 00:00:00') and ('2011-04-26 00:00:00')
group by 
  employee.employee_no, employee.employee_first_name, employee.employee_last_name, employee.home_store_no
order by 1
```

Comment: +1 It is not possible to *and* return the transaction dates, *and* have one row for each employee.

Comment: You could of course get the maximum / minimum / average / ... transaction dates and discount amounts.